# How to store CSV data into an array in C#?

Tags: c#, console

I have a CSV file which has **9 columns**. (Date,DrawNumber,N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,B1)

Below the above columns are **55 rows** of data.

The data in the rows are separated by the (,) delimiter.

---

1) In a console application, the user will input 6/7 numbers which will be stored.

2.) How do I read and save the CSV data into array(s) in such a way where I can count how many times each number (of the users inputted set of 6 or 7 numbers) were found in the entire CSV (from these columns: N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,B1). Example: Number 33 = Found 12 Times, Number 14 found 11 Times,... (and so on for the remainder of the inputted numbers)

3.)From the 6 or 7 numbers that the user will input, I will also have to see how many numbers (of the user's input) will match with **each row** of the CSV. In other words, I have to match combinations per row (N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,B1)

---

What would be the best way of reading and storing the data to allow for such data manipulations? (your sample code will be appreciated) ?

Thanks in advance.

EXAMPLE OF CSV DATA:

[image: EXAMPLE OF CSV DATA:]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a CSV file in to an array using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102804/read-a-csv-file-in-to-an-array-using-c-sharp)

Comment: This reads a bit like homework, and is not a specific question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing CSV files in C#, with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-with-header)

Answer (score 0):

create a class that matches the column
so lets say having 9 columns means 9 properties.

```
public class CsvData
{
    public string column1 { get; set; }
    public string column2 { get; set; }
    public string column3 { get; set; }
    public string column4 { get; set; }
    public string column5 { get; set; }
    public string column6 { get; set; }
    public string column7 { get; set; }
    public string column8 { get; set; }
    public string column9 { get; set; }
}
```

when now lest map the csv file into  list of CsvData object

```
public List<CsvData> ReadCsv(string file)
{
    List<CsvData> collection = new List<CsvData>();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] columns = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(';');

            CsvData data = new CsvData();
            data.column1 = columns[0];
            data.column2 = columns[1];
            data.column3 = columns[2];
            data.column4 = columns[3];
            data.column5 = columns[4];
            data.column6 = columns[5];
            data.column7 = columns[6];
            data.column8 = columns[7];
            data.column9 = columns[8];

            collection.Add(data);
        }
    }

    return collection;
}
```

Now for calculating rows containing a number or term

```
public int CountRowsWithTerm(List<CsvData> collection, string term)
{
    List<CsvData> RowsContainingTheTerm = collection.Where(row => row.column1 == term || row.column2 == term || row.column3 == term ||
                            row.column4 == term || row.column5 == term || row.column6 == term ||
                            row.column7 == term || row.column8 == term || row.column9 == term).ToList();
    return RowsContainingTheTerm.Count();
}
```

hope this helped